# Size of integral symbol in section header with mlmodern

Tags: fonts, section-titles, mlmodern

I really like the font `\usepackage{mlmodern}` and want to keep using it. Only when using `\int` in a section header, the integral sign for some reason shrinks in size relative to the rest of the expression. This happens with both pdflatex and also lualatex.

Why does this happen and is there a way to keep the integral sign from shrinking?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}  
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mlmodern}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{$ \int \sqrt{1+2 x} \, dx$}
    This is a test
    \[
    \int \sqrt{1+2 x} \, dx
    \]    
    \end{document}
```

Compiled using pdflatex or lualatex gives

[image]

Compare to the output from

```
    \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}  
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{$ \int \sqrt{1+2 x} \, dx$}
    This is a test
    \[
    \int \sqrt{1+2 x} \, dx
    \]
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At least I can reproduce the problem :).

Comment: See my not-answer, maybe the `\int` symbol has a maximum size?! The `amsmath` package does not seem to be relevant, in the MWE right?

Comment: I looked into the code of the `mlmodern` package [2021/01/12 v1.1] and found that the line `\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}` causes the difference in the size of the integral. The corresponding `fd` file (`omxmlmex.fd`) includes the following macro call: `\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{<->sfixed*mlmex10}{}`. Based on page 21 at https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf, the size functions `fixed` or `sfixed` "Load font ⟨fontarg⟩ as is, disregarding the user-requested size. If present, ⟨optarg⟩ gives the “at . . . pt” size to be used." (1 of 2)

Comment: That is, the font size you indicate is ignored. Now, when I changed `sfixed` to just `s` and compiled the TeX file, the integral returned to its normal, desired size. That is, the macro code was changed to `\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{<->s*mlmex10}{}`. The size function `s` is described as "Load the external font ⟨fontarg⟩ at the user-requested size. If
⟨optarg⟩ is present, it is used as the scale-factor." (2 of 2)

Comment: @Nasser, have you tried the possible change that was described in the 2 comments above? Please let us know if it worked, or if you encountered any issues while applying this change. Thank you!

Comment: @MiriamBriskman, those comments really look like an answer... 

Comment: @Rmano, thank you! I was first awaiting a possible reply from Nasser on whether this suggested change actually works before putting it up as an answer. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your note, and I might try composing an answer before receiving a reply. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** As **egreg** correctly noted in the comments below, the change that we describe in the answer here will last temporarily since, on a subsequent update of the package, the change we propose will be wiped out from the `mlmodern` font declaration.

As such, egreg recommends including a font family declaration within the `TeX` file, before `begin{document}`, similar to:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mlmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->mlmex10%
   }{}
```

Another possibility is to creat a package that is using `mlmodern` and containing a similar declaration and use this package in your `TeX` file, which avoids the need to include the font family declaration in each and every future `TeX` project.

---

***Disclaimer:** This solution involves making a change to the settings of the `mlmodern` package. Please be advised that, in general, changing a package may affect its functionality, so any changes you decide to make are at your own discretion.*

---

### Solution (Keeping Things Short)

To have `\int` displayed at the font size of your choice (in your case, 12pt):

1. Find the `mlmodern` directory (in which the `mlmodern.sty` package file resides) on your computer.

   - If you are using texlive on Linux, you may find the package at `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/` or `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`.
   - If you are using MiKTeX on Windows, you may find the package at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`.
     [image]
2. In this directory are numerous `.fd` (font definition) files. Open the file `omxmlmex.fd` for editing.
3. Change the macro call

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
 <->sfixed*mlmex10%
 }{}
```

in this file to

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
 <->s*mlmex10% % <----- sfixed was changed to s
 }{}
```

[image]
4. Re-compile your TeX file, and you'll see that the integral symbol shows the correct size.
[image]

---

### Explanation

**Note:** The solution-search procedure described below was done on a Windows 10 device but can be applied on a Mac or Linux computer in a similar fashion.

#### Diagnosis

It is evident that the integral symbol was displayed with incorrect sizing.

Moreover, **Dr. Manuel Kuehner** showed in his test at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646334/256551 that setting a different font size didn't change the size of `\int`.

#### Digging up

The fact that commenting `\usepackage{mlmodern}` out brings the integral back to its desired size implies that the issue is rooted in the `mlmodern` package.

As such, we decided to view the `mlmodern.sty` file, most of which contains calls to `\SetSymbolFont` and `\SetMathAlphabet`:

```
%This package provides support for the mlmodern fonts. See mlmodern.pdf
%for more information.
%This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
%of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this
%license or (at your option) any later version.
%Copyright 2003--2009 by B. Jackowski and J.M. Nowacki.
%Copyright 2021 by Daniel Benjamin Miller.
%This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%The Current Maintainer of this work is Daniel Benjamin Miller.


\ProvidesPackage{mlmodern}[2021/01/12 v1.1 Modified Latin Modern Fonts]

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{mlmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{mlmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{mlmtt}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}
\DeclareOption{nomath}{\endinput}
\DeclareOption{variablett}{%
  \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{mlmvtt}
}
\DeclareOption{lighttt}{%
  \let\mlmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{mlmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal}{OML}{mlmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal}{OMS}{mlmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {OT1}{mlmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}  {OML}{mlmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}  {OMS}{mlmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OT1}{mlmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OT1}{mlmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{mlmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{mlmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}  {OT1}{mlmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}  {OT1}{mlmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}  {OT1}{mlmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}  {OT1}{mlmtt}{m}{n}

\def\mathsterling{\mathit{\mathchar"70BF}}

\endinput
```

To check which of the calls influences the formatting of the integral, we commented out each of the calls, one at a time, and compiled the TeX file.

It turns out that the call

```
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}
```

sets the formatting (font encoding + family) of `\int` (and other large math operators, like `\sum` and `\prod`, as page 12 in https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf mentions.)

Based on page 14, `\SetSymbolFont` has the synopsis:

```
\SetMathAlphabet {⟨math-alph⟩} {⟨version⟩} {⟨encoding⟩} {⟨family⟩} {⟨series⟩} {⟨shape⟩}
```

and is defined to change the symbol font ⟨sym-font⟩ for math version ⟨version⟩ to ⟨encoding⟩ ⟨family⟩ ⟨series⟩ ⟨shape⟩.

The font attributes of the `OMX` encoding and `mlmex` font family are specified in the `omxmlmex.fd` file, which is contained in the folder of `mlmodern.sty`, so the next step was to look into the file.

#### Finding the issue's source

The content of `omxmlmex.fd` is:

```
%This package provides support for the mlmodern fonts. See mlmodern.pdf
%for more information.
%This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
%of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this
%license or (at your option) any later version.
%Copyright 2003--2009 by B. Jackowski and J.M. Nowacki.
%Copyright 2021 by Daniel Benjamin Miller.
%This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%The Current Maintainer of this work is Daniel Benjamin Miller.

\ProvidesFile{omxmlmex.fd}[2021/01/11 v1.0 Font defs for mlmodern]

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mlmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*mlmex10%
   }{}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `omxmlmex.fd'.
```

Notice the macro call `\DeclareFontShape` and, specifically, its 5th argument, `<->sfixed*mlmex10`.

According to page 18, this argument "contains the information that combines sizes with external fonts. "

Section 4.3 (pages 19-20) in the document tells that `<->` is the range of font sizes on which this rule is applied (in our case, any font size), `sfixed` is a size function, and `mlmex10` is the font argument `⟨fontarg⟩` of the size function.

Now, `sfixed` in particular "loads font ⟨fontarg⟩ as is, disregarding the user-requested size." Given that `mlmex10` is a font argument corresponding to a font of size 10pt, the entire argument simply **keeps all the symbols at size 10pt, regardless of the user's attempts to change it.**

#### Solving the issue

The solution, based on the findings above, is to opt for a different size function that allows the user to customize the font size. A function that meets this condition is `s`, which is defined on page 20 as loading "the external font ⟨fontarg⟩ at the user-requested size."

When we change `sfixed` to `s`, and then recompile the TeX file, the `\int` symbol is displayed at the font of 12pt, as desired.

---

### Final Comments

I am unable to tell whether the use of the `sfixed` size function is an intentional decision of the developers of `mlmodern` or if it is a bug. In any case, I would recommend to notify the maintainer of `mlmodern`, Daniel Benjamin Miller, about the issue that `sfixed` caused.

Hopefully, this approach above addressed your question! If it hasn't, I will be more than happy to adjust the answer accordingly to adequately address your question.

Comment: Modifying a distributed file is a no-go. An update to the package would destroy the edit. It's *much* simpler to add the font family declaration in the document (and `s*` is not needed).

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much for your important comment! What change should be done, then, if we wish to apply the change to any future TeX file, without including the declaration in each file? Thank you again!

Comment: Write a package similar to `fixcmex` and upload it to CTAN. When and if `mlmodern` changes to allow arbitrary size, the package can be made into a no-op.

Comment: @egreg, this is a wonderful approach. Thank you very much! Would you like to make an edit to the answer that reflects the concern that the edit will be gone on a subsequent update, and that building a package will address the issue, just as you explained? You raised this important concern, so it is your right to edit the answer. Thank you very much for your great contribution!

Comment: The answer is yours. I gave an answer that I removed as per your request (the gratuitous and undeserved downvote is not how the site works, by the way). I'm not going to change answers unless they contain serious errors. The responsibility is on the poster.

Answer (score 3):

*Not an answer, just a test.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

\begin{document}

\section{$ \int \sqrt{2x^2}$}
$ \int \sqrt{2x^2}$

\end{document}
```

### LuaLaTeX Output

[image]

[image]

### pdfLaTeX Output

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit**

Maybe the integral symbol is just not available in a size that large, see the following MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

\begin{document}

\section{$ \int \sqrt{2x^2}$}

$ \int \sqrt{2x^2}$

{\huge $ \int \sqrt{2x^2}$} % <-- \huge

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the test. I assume then you agree the integral sign should be larger in section header.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, I agree. See also my edit. (going offline now)