# Tikz-cd diagram with beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex, tikz-cd

In the following beamer code,

```
\RequirePackage{plautopatch}

\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames,table,dvipdfmx]{beamer}
\usepackage{bxdpx-beamer} % dvipdfmxなので必要

%Beamerの設定
\usetheme{Boadilla}

%シャーの定義
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}

%Beamerフォント設定
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % Be professional!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}  % 太いComputer Modern

% MLmodernのバグを修正: cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646333/size-of-integral-symbol-in-section-header-with-mlmodern
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mlmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
    <->mlmex10%
}{}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % 数式以外をTXフォントで上書き
\usepackage[deluxe,uplatex]{otf} % 日本語多ウェイト化
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  % 英文をサンセリフ体に
\renewcommand{\kanjifamilydefault}{\gtdefault}  % 日本語をゴシック体に
\usefonttheme{structurebold} % タイトル部を太字
\setbeamerfont{alertedtext}{series=\bfseries} % Alertを太字
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{series=\mdseries} % 目次は太字にしない
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large} % フレームタイトル文字サイズ
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE} % タイトル文字サイズ
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}  % 日付文字サイズ

% Babel (日本語の場合のみ・英語の場合は不要)
\uselanguage{japanese}
\languagepath{japanese}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Theorem}{定理}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Lemma}{補題}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Example}{例}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Examples}{例}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Definition}{定義}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Definitions}{定義}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Problem}{問題}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Solution}{解}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Fact}{事実}
\deftranslation[to=japanese]{Proof}{証明}
\def\proofname{証明}

%Beamer色設定
\definecolor{UniBlue}{RGB}{0,150,200} 
\definecolor{AlertOrange}{RGB}{255,76,0}
\definecolor{AlmostBlack}{RGB}{38,38,38}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=AlmostBlack}  % 本文カラー
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UniBlue} % 見出しカラー
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=UniBlue!50!black} % ブロック部分タイトルカラー
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=AlertOrange} % \alert
文字カラー
\mode<beamer>{
    \definecolor{BackGroundGray}{RGB}{254,254,254}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=BackGroundGray} % スライドモードのみ背景をわずかにグレーにする
}

%フラットデザイン化
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded] % Blockの影を消す
\useinnertheme{circles} % 箇条書きをシンプルに
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % ナビゲーションシンボルを消す
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] % フッターはスライド番号のみ

%タイトルページ
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
    \vspace{2.5em}
    {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}
    \vspace{1.5em}
    \begin{flushright}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
        \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
        \vspace{3em}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
    \end{flushright}
}

% Algorithm系
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\algsetup{linenosize=\color{fg!50}\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\algorithmicdo{:}
\renewcommand\algorithmicthen{:}
\renewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}

% 定理
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newenvironment{mythm}{\begin{alertblock}{定理}}{\end{alertblock}} %自分の結果は赤色で表示

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideallsubsections]} %目次スライド
}
```

I want to add the following diagram, but the output is broken.
What preamble or code I should add to add the following diagram correctly?
The following code is correct because it outputs the correct diagram in usual pdflatex.

```
$$
\require{}\begin{CD}
    \\
    kerF@>>>\Sha(E/K)@>>> kerH\\
    @VVV@VVV @VVV\\
    H^1(G,E(L))@>\text{inf}>>H^1(G_K,E)@>\text{res}>>\text{res}H^1(G_K,E)\\
    @VVFV @VVG V @VVHV\\
    \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(\text{Gal}(L_w/K_v),E(L_w))}}@>a>>\bigoplus_{v\in M_K}{H^1(G_{K_v},E)}}@>>>\bigoplus_{v\in M_K}{res(H^1(G_{K_v},E})}\\ 
    @VVV @VbVV\\
    \text{coker}F@>j>>\text{coker}G\\
\end{CD}
$$
```

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frame{\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}

\section{局所大域原理}
\begin{frame}{局所大域原理}

\begin{Definition}
 $K$を代数体とし, $M_K$を$K$の素点全体の集合とする. 
 $K_v$を$K$の$v\in M_K$における完備化とする. 
 $X/K$を$K$上定義された代数多様体とする. 

 $X/K$において局所大域原理が成り立つとは
 \[X(K)\neq \emptyset \iff X(K_v)\neq \emptyset, \forall v\in M_K\]
 が成り立つときのことをいう. 
\end{Definition}

\begin{Theorem}(Hasse-Minkovskiの定理)
 $K$を標数0の代数体 $a,b\in K^{\times}$とする. 
 $K$上の２次形式$ax^2+by^2=0$において局所大域原理が成り立つ. 
\end{Theorem}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{局所大域原理の反例}

    \begin{exampleblock}{Counter example(Lind,1950)}
 $2y^2=x^4-17$は局所大域原理を満たさない.
  \end{exampleblock} 

\end{frame}

\section{楕円曲線}


\begin{frame}{楕円曲線}
\begin{Definition}
種数1の代数曲線で有理点を持つものを楕円曲線という.
例. $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$は$\Bbb{Q}$上の楕円曲線ではないが, $x^3+y^3+60z^3=0$は楕円曲線である.
\end{Definition}
\item 有理点の集合$E(K)$には有限生成アーベル群の群構造が入る.
\begin{Theorem}
 群$E(K)$は有限生成なアーベル群である.よって
 $E(K)\cong \Bbb{Z}^{\text{rank}(E/K)}\times E(K)_{\text{tor}}$($E_{tor}$は有限アーベル群)
 とかける.
 $\text{rank}(E/K)$を$E/K$のランクといい, $E(K)_{\text{tor}}$を$E/K$の捩れ部分という.
 また, $E(K)/2E(K)$を弱\text{Mordel-Weil}群という.

\end{Theorem}


\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{ガロアコホモロジー}
\begin{Definition}

 $K$を標数$0$の体, $G=\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$をその絶対ガロア群, $M$を$G$上の加群とする.
 今, $M$に$G$は連続に作用しているとする($M$には離散位相, $G$にはKrull位相を入れている.). 
 $H^0(G,M)=M^G\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{m\in M \mid \forall \sigma \in G, \sigma{m}-m=0\}$

$H^1(G,M)\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\dfrac{\{f:G\to M :\text{連続写像} \mid f(\sigma \tau)=f(\sigma)+\sigma f(\tau), \forall \sigma,\tau \in  G\}}{\{f:G\to M:\text{連続写像}\mid \exists m \in M, \forall \sigma \in G, f(\sigma)=\sigma m-m\}}$


\end{Definition}

\end{frame}

\section{Tate-Shafarevich群}
\begin{Definition} $K$を代数体とする. 
$\Sha(E/K)\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \text{ker}(H^1(G_K,E) \to \prod_{v\in M_K} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)})$を$E/K$のTate-Shafarevich群という
.\end{Definition}
ガロアコホモロジーの定義を見ているだけではすぐにはわからないが, 局所大域原理と関係している. Tate-Shafarevich群の元は, torsor(トーサー)と呼ばれる元と同一視され, 幾何学的には局所大域原理の成り立たなさの度合いを測る.
\begin{Definition}
$K$を代数体とする. $E/K$のtorsor$(C,\mu)$とは, $K$上の曲線と$K$上の射$\mu: E\times C\to C$の組であって,$C(\overline{K})$にsimply transitiveな作用を誘導するものである. 
\end{Definition}

\begin{frame}

$\Sha(E/K)$は局所大域原理が成り立つ主等質空間で代表される元１つと, その他の局所大域原理が成り立たない主等質空間で代表される元たちからなる集合である. すなわち, 

\begin{align*}
\Sha(E/K) &= \{\text{localに有理点を持つ$E/K$-torsorの同型類の集合}\} \\ 
&= \{[E/K]\} \bigcup \left\{
  [C/K]
  \;\middle|\;
  \begin{aligned}
  & C \text{: } E/K\text{-torsor s.t. } C(K) = \emptyset, \\
  & \ C(K_v) \neq \emptyset, \forall v \in M_K   
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{align*}
である.




\end{frame}

\section{体拡大における挙動}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{exampleblock}{私の問題意識}
体を$\Bbb{Q}$から$K$に拡大したときに, $\Sha(E/K)$の$\Sha(E/\Bbb{Q})$と比べたときの挙動はどうなるか？
\end{exampleblock} 

\begin{exampleblock}{すぐわかること}
体を拡大すると$\Sha(E/K)$の元が有理点を持ち, $0$になる元はある. 一方, $\Bbb{Q}$上にはなかった$K$上の局所大域原理の反例が増えて, $\Sha(E/K)$の位数は大きくなるかもしれない.
一概には, $\Bbb{Q}$を$K$に変えた時, $\Sha(E/K)$は$\Sha(E/\Bbb{Q})$に比べて増加するか減少するかすぐにはわからない.
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}


\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{体拡大したときのランクについて}

\begin{Lemma}
 $L/K$を体の２次拡大とし, $E/K$を$K$上の楕円曲線とする.
$L=K(\sqrt{D})$とすると, 
\[\text{rank}(E/L)=\text{rank}(E/K)+\text{rank}(E_D/K)\]である. 
\end{Lemma}



\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{主結果}
   
    \vfill
    \begin{exampleblock}{主結果1:減らす}
$p$を奇素数とし, $E:y^2=x^3+px$を楕円曲線とする. \par
$\Sha(E/K)[2]=0$ もしくは $\Sha(E/K)[2]\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$となる虚２次体$K$が無数に存在する. 
  \end{exampleblock} 
    \vfill
 \end{frame}  
  
\begin{exampleblock}{主結果2:増やす}
任意の整数$r$と任意の楕円曲線$E/\Bbb{Q}$に対して,ある2次体$K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$が存在して, \[\dfrac{\#\Sha(E/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))}{\#\Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})}\ge r\]が成り立つ. 
\end{exampleblock}   
   
\end{frame}



\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please rework and complete the code you posted. In its current state it‘s hard to use and almost impossible to use. Thank you

Comment: Please make a *minimal* reproducible example. It should include everything necessary to reproduce the problem, but not more. If you don't need any special fonts and encodings, you will dramatically increase the pool of people, who are able to help you. Please also state which engine etc. you use to compile your code.

Comment: There is no `\require` in LaTeX. The last code is MathJax, isn't it? And it's an `amscd` diagram, not `tikz-cd`.

Comment: @egreg what kind of modification resque this code ?

Comment: If I get you right, this might help you on a practical level: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction None. See my answer, though.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction Please do not just dump all your code into your question. Previous commenters have already asked you to produce a minimal working example, which should contain only what is absolutely necessary to produce your `tikz-cd` diagram.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to produce an `amscd` diagram, not a `tikz-cd` one, but the MathJax code you provide isn't working, contrary of what you claim.

Here's a somewhat working version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{CD}
kerF@>>>\Sha(E/K)@>>> kerH
\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV
\\
H^1(G,E(L)) @>\text{inf}>> H^1(G_K,E) @>\text{res}>> \text{res} H^1(G_K,E) \\
@VV{F}V @VV{G}V @VV{H}V
\\
\bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(\text{Gal}(L_w/K_v),E(L_w)) @>a>> \bigoplus_{v\in M_K} H^1(G_{K_v},E) @>>> \bigoplus_{v\in M_K} res(H^1(G_{K_v},E)
\\ 
@VVV @VbVV
\\
\text{coker}F@>j>>\text{coker}G
\\
\end{CD}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not really what I'd like to see nowadays. Here's an implementation with `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}

\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\ker F \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \Sha(E/K) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \ker H \arrow[d]
\\
H^1(G,E(L)) \arrow[r,"\inf"] \arrow[d,"F"] & 
H^1(G_K,E) \arrow[r,"\res"] \arrow[d,"G"] & 
\res H^1(G_K,E) \arrow[d,"H"]
\\
\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} H^1(\Gal(L_w/K_v),E(L_w)) \arrow[r,"a"] \arrow[d] &
\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} H^1(G_{K_v},E) \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"b"] &
\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} \res(H^1(G_{K_v},E)
\\
\coker F \arrow[r,"j"] & \coker G
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your case, the code

```
\begin{frame}{Diagram}

\footnotesize
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\ker F \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \& \Sha(E/K) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \& \ker H \arrow[d]
\\
H^1(G,E(L)) \arrow[r,"\inf"] \arrow[d,"F"] \&
H^1(G_K,E) \arrow[r,"\res"] \arrow[d,"G"] \&
\res H^1(G_K,E) \arrow[d,"H"]
\\
\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} H^1(\Gal(L_w/K_v),E(L_w)) \arrow[r,"a"] \arrow[d] \&
\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} H^1(G_{K_v},E) \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"b"] \&
\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} \res(H^1(G_{K_v},E)
\\
\coker F \arrow[r,"j"] \& \coker G
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{frame}
```

produces a diagram that fits in the slide.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code worked. I really thank you for your help. But the diagram is too big and it protrude my slide. How can I make it smaller ?

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction I added a workaround for your beamer presentation.